# How to show keys instead values of an associative array on Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I´m new on Laravel and I´m trying to display on a select the keys instead the values of an associative array...

Could you help me?

The array I´m working with is this:

```
"MaritalStatusCode" => [
        "Vacio" => "SINGLE",
        "Casado_gananciales" => "MARRIED",
        "Casado_separacion_bienes" => "MARRIED",
        "pareja_hecho" => "COHABITING",
        "Divorciado" => "DIVORCED",
        "Soltero" => "SINGLE",
        "Viudo" => "WIDOWED",
        "otros" => "SINGLE",
    ],
```

I would like the left values being shown on the next select:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="form-group">
     {{Form::label("Estado civil")}}
     {{Form::select('MaritalStatusCode', 
                    $a_values["MaritalStatusCode"], 
                    @$user["MaritalSituation"]["MaritalStatusCode"], 
                    ["class" =>  "form-control", 'readonly'])}}
   </div>
</div>
```

This select is displaying the values,

Sorry if I´ve made a bad explanation and hope you could help me,

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using array_keys as below,

```
{{Form::select('MaritalStatusCode', 
                array_keys($a_values["MaritalStatusCode"]), 
                @$user["MaritalSituation"]["MaritalStatusCode"], 
                ["class" =>  "form-control", 'readonly'])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_keys()` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`array_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

in your case it would be something like this

```
{{Form::select('MaritalStatusCode',array_keys($a_values["MaritalStatusCode"]), @$user["MaritalSituation"]["MaritalStatusCode"], ["class" =>  "form-control", 'readonly'])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used array_flip instead of array_keys.

The reason is because array_keys affected the data we send using our form, but array_flip not,

Thanks a lot for your time, you´re so kind...

Bernardo.